# Finding all sublists of size N in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, instantiation-error

I'm new to Prolog and I got stuck on writing this predicate. Basically I'm given a list and I need to find the most common sublist of size N. Examples:

1. `most_common_sublist([1,2,2,3,2,2,4,2,2,3],1,L)`, output should be `L=[2]`;
2. `most_common_sublist([1,2,2,3,2,2,4,2,2,3],2,L)`, output should be `L=[2,2]`;
3. `most_common_sublist([1,2,2,3,2,2,4,2,2,3],3,L)`, output should be `L=[2,2,3]`;

My approach was to write a predicate that gets the first N elements of the list, write a second predicate that will act like a generator (calling the first predicate over and over until the list is shortened to size N), and then check for all of the generated sublists how many times there was match and get the maximum of that.

I got stuck on the generator predicate the rest I'm pretty sure I know how to write.

This is my code so far:

```
length([],0).
length([_|L],N) :- N is M+1, length(L,M).

// This will get the first N elements from the list. 
// I tested it and it works.
sublist([H|_],1,[H]).
sublist([H|T],N,[H|LOP]) :- M is N-1, sublist(T,M,LOP).

// This is supposed to generate all the sublists, 
// length is a predicate that returns the length of the list. 
generator(L,N,L) :- length(L,M), N=:=M.
generator([H|T],N,[PN|LOP]) :- sublist([H|T],N,PN), generator(T,N,LOP).
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
?- generator([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],2,X).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [12] _6018 is _6024+1
ERROR:   [11] length([1,2|...],_6052) at c:/users/ace_m/documents/prolog/bp.pl:44
ERROR:   [10] generator([1,2|...],2,[1,2|...]) at c:/users/ace_m/documents/prolog/bp.pl:83
ERROR:    [9] <user>
   Exception: (10) generator([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 2, _5204) ?
```

I understand that the error means that I'm not passing the correct values, but I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Any help

Comment: Your error refers to an expression using `+`, but none of your posted code does.

Comment: @ScottHunter i guess that's from the length predicate, I put that in my code as well.

Comment: 1) Why not use the built-in `length/2` instead of using your own? 2) Sublist is correctly written, but you can write it easier with: `sublist(L,N,SL) :- length(SL,N), append(SL,_,L)` 3) In generator/3, 1st clause, M is uninstantiated on call to length/2, so computing N is M+1 will fail

Comment: 4) Can you use tabling? Because this sounds like a case for ... [mode-directed tabling](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling-mode-directed) (hey, it's time to use other features than Prolog's oldies from the 90s)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I'm not supposed to use the built-in predicates, I'm supposed to write them myself sadly... I guess it's for the best since that is the best way to learn the stuff, thank you for replying though i solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable in an arithmetic expression before it has been bound to a value.